# Which page in main memory does the process' page 4 map to?

Tags: paging

Got a question:

A process has the following page table.

```
Valid Bit     Page

   
    0        -
    1        3
    0        -
    0        -
    1        2
    1        0
    0        -
    1        1
```

Which page in main memory does the process' page 4 map to?

Select one:

a.
4

b.
2

c.
0

d.
Page 4 of the process is not stored in main memory

e.
None of the above

I would have thought it was (d) since (3,2,0,1) are valid and 4 is not present. But the answer is 2 apparently and I don't see why?

What is the mistake in this solution:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nBYY.jpg

Comment: Assuming page 0 is at the top and page 7 is at the bottom, then page 4 (the fifth page) will map to in-memory page number `2`.

Comment: uploaded a pic of the solution: https://imgur.com/a/HCc0kmu (what is the mistake here) @Someprogrammerdude